# Publishing arrays unsuccessful

Tags: ros, rostopic-echo, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have been following this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/9471/how-to-recieve-an-array-over-publisher-and-subscriber-python/) very closely.

This is how mine looks like:

> ```
> def talker(armj_acc) :
> ```

> ```
>     pub10 = rospy.Publisher('/armj_acc', obs_arm_JointAccelerations)
> ```

> ```
>     msg2send10 = obs_arm_JointAccelerations()
>     msg2send10.header.stamp.secs = time_now
>     msg2send10.accelerations = armj_acc
>     pub10.publish(msg2send10)
> ```

I have my own custom message, by the name *obs_arm_JointAccelerations* which contains

> ```
> Header header 
> float64[] accelerations
> ```

The variable armj_acc is actually a list whose values have been successfully calculated and passed into the function, which I print them on the screen. The calculation for the armj_acc is done via subscribing velocities from the /joint_states topic, every 4 seconds ((current velocity - previous velocity) /4).

The problem is, whenever I try to echo the topic, it gives me the following error:

(1) In the terminal where the topic is being echo-ed

> WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
> Is /clock being published?

(2) In the terminal where the code is run:

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1367266510.640556] [5269.097000] bad callback: <function callback at 0x2f6e1b8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 678, in _invoke_callback
cb(msg)
File "/home/path/to/my/package/script/obs_armj_all.py", line 47, in callback
talker(armj_names, armj_act_positions, armj_act_velocities, armj_effort_act, armj_effort_diff, armj_pos_rel_diff)#, armj_acc)#, armj_jerk)
File "/home/path/to/my/package/script/obs_armj_all.py", line 185, in talker
pub10.publish(msg2send10)
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 796, in publish
raise ROSSerializationException(str(e))
ROSSerializationException: cannot convert argument to integer

Any ideas?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61775/publishing-arrays-unsuccessful/) by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2013-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your posted code matches what you're running, it looks like you're publishing the wrong variable.  You're trying to publish the `armj_acc` array directly, rather than the `msg2send10` message.  I'm also not sure that you're allowed to assign a time directly to the header field like you've shown.

Try this:

```
def talker(armj_acc) :
    pub10 = rospy.Publisher('/armj_acc', obs_arm_JointAccelerations)

    msg2send10 = obs_arm_JointAccelerations()
    msg2send10.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    msg2send10.accelerations = armj_acc
    pub10.publish(msg2send10)
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) on 2013-04-29**:
I edited that one, it is now: msg2send10.header.stamp.secs = time_now, where time_now = rospy.Time.now(), which is actually wrong. It is supposed to be: msg2send10.header.stamp.secs = time_now.secs... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publishers take a little while to register themselves with the master. By creating a publisher and then publishing a message immediately, the publisher has likely not finished registering, so the message will be lost. Try sleeping a little bit before before publishing, or (if appropriate) publishing inside a loop.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1